# Authenticating PubSub Push messages in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a way to know for sure that a message received by app engine is from the Google PubSub service? Currently the PubSub service gets a 302 on the URLs configured as "login: admin" in appengine app.yaml. So it keeps retrying.

I would have expected this to behave like the Tasks in Appengine and automatically authenticate to "login:admin" URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/faq#security) recommends that when setting up your PubSub push subscription you put a shared secret token as a request parameter which you check for in your handler.

> If you additionally would like to verify that the messages originated from Google Cloud Pub/Sub, you could configure your endpoint to only accept messages that are accompanied by a secret token argument, for example,
>
> `https://myapp.mydomain.com/myhandler?token=application-secret.`

Since PubSub does not use appengine authentication and we are using the token to authenticate you should not specify a `login` key in your app.yaml entry for this handler. Here's an example:

**main.py**

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        token = self.request.params['token']

        if token != 'foo':
            self.abort(401, 'Not authorized')

        # do stuff


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', Handler),
], debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```